# unix command for extracting start of line based on delimiter

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I have a Unix command that outputs file contents with each line prefixed by the respective file name:

```
C:\lessgov.txt | WHY LESS GOVERNMENT IS BETTER GOVERNMENT
C:\lessgov.txt | A rant...

C:\todos.txt | TODOS
C:\todos.txt | buy bread
C:\todos.txt | shine shoes
```

What precise command can I use to remove everything after and including the vertical bar?  (I am thinking `sed` but I've no real idea how to use it if I'm right.)

```
C:\lessgov.txt
C:\lessgov.txt

C:\todos.txt
C:\todos.txt
C:\todos.txt
```

I am actually using Windows but I have a port of most of the Unix commands at my disposal.

EDIT:

This worked.

```
cmd> search $dirs | tail -n5 | concat --prefix | grep CPCMS | sed "s/|.*//"
```

`search` and `concat` are custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few choices here, here's a sed solution if you need to strip the space before the `|`

```
 sed 's/ *|.*//' file.txt
```

to retain the space before the `|`

```
 sed 's/|.*//' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The most verbose and easy-to-remember command I can think of is [cut](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/):

> ```
>  cut -- cut out selected portions of each line of a file
>  [...]
>  -d delim
>          Use delim as the field delimiter character instead of the tab
>          character.
>
>  -f list
>          The list specifies fields, separated in the input by the field
>          delimiter character (see the -d option.)  Output fields are sepa-
>          rated by a single occurrence of the field delimiter character.
>  [...]
>  -s      Suppress lines with no field delimiter characters.  Unless speci-
>          fied, lines with no delimiters are passed through unmodified.
> ```

`-fN` says "select the Nth field", while `-dC` says "splitting by character C".

In your case, `cat the_file | cut -f1 -d'|'`:

```
$ cat the_file 
C:\lessgov.txt | WHY LESS GOVERNMENT IS BETTER GOVERNMENT
C:\lessgov.txt | A rant...

C:\todos.txt | TODOS
C:\todos.txt | buy bread
C:\todos.txt | shine shoes
$ cat the_file | cut -f1 -d'|'
C:\lessgov.txt 
C:\lessgov.txt 

C:\todos.txt 
C:\todos.txt 
C:\todos.txt
```

If you want to leave that blank line out, add `-s` switch and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

many unix tools can do that job,

Assume you don't have spaces in your file/dir names:
e.g `grep`:

```
grep -o '^\S\+' file
```

awk:

```
awk '{print $1}' file
```

or

```
awk '$0=$1' file
```

sed, cut .... can do it too.

If you have spaces in your path, it is not hard either to be handled, just playing with the FS/Separator expression.